# How to recreate a comic book panel transition with my canvas (simple 2D background art)?

Tags: unity, 2d, gui, unity-ui

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tqqf5Y8LyR8&t=23s&ab_channel=ErikLoyer

So I want to achieve a transition like from the above video, specifically at 0:23 the TRACK, but there is a 3 Dimensional perspective to it. PUSH seems like the one I am talking about, but lets say the image(i.e panel in the video) gets pushed off camera and gets destroyed. How can I achieve this in Unity 2d?

Comment: I would do that with an animation controller or a timeline. Are you familiar with these?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three ways to achieve this, which one you choose depends on the particulars of your project.

## Script

You can animate your UI elements by manipulating the values of their `RectTransform` components during `Update` or a coroutine. The [`AnimationCurve`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html) class makes it quite easy to create ease-in and ease-out or bouncy effects.

## Animation Clips

You could [author animation clips](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-UsingAnimationEditor.html) for your canvas elements that then are [triggered](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StateMachineBasics.html) by some user action (a "next" button, perhaps?)

## Timeline

The Unity [Timeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.timeline@1.6/manual/index.html) is similar to creating individual animation clips but is more global in nature. This approach might make a lot of sense if there is only ever one way to move through the content.

## or some combination

All these methods can be combined, mixed and matched.